# What arguments get passed with PG_FUNCTION_ARGS (with the V1 convention)?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions, c

PostgreSQL Documents all their C functions with a "V1" interface, but they don't actually show what they get,

```c
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(add_one);

Datum
add_one(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    int32   arg = PG_GETARG_INT32(0);

    PG_RETURN_INT32(arg + 1);
}
```

In the above what does `PG_FUNCTION_ARGS` declare the function to accept? Many V1 function seem to have a `fcinfo` magically show up in the definition, I'm guessing it's brought in here but what is it and does anything else get brought in with this macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual definition for this is in [`fmgr.h`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/c30f54ad732ca5c8762bb68bbe0f51de9137dd72/src/include/fmgr.h#L193),

```
#define PG_FUNCTION_ARGS    FunctionCallInfo fcinfo
```

This [is a pointer to `FunctionCallInfoBaseData`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/c30f54ad732ca5c8762bb68bbe0f51de9137dd72/src/include/fmgr.h#L38)

```
typedef struct FunctionCallInfoBaseData *FunctionCallInfo;
```

And [you can see the definition of that in the same file](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/c30f54ad732ca5c8762bb68bbe0f51de9137dd72/src/include/fmgr.h#L85),

```c
typedef struct FunctionCallInfoBaseData
{
    FmgrInfo   *flinfo;         /* ptr to lookup info used for this call */
    fmNodePtr   context;        /* pass info about context of call */
    fmNodePtr   resultinfo;     /* pass or return extra info about result */
    Oid         fncollation;    /* collation for function to use */
#define FIELDNO_FUNCTIONCALLINFODATA_ISNULL 4
    bool        isnull;         /* function must set true if result is NULL */
    short       nargs;          /* # arguments actually passed */
#define FIELDNO_FUNCTIONCALLINFODATA_ARGS 6
    NullableDatum args[FLEXIBLE_ARRAY_MEMBER];
} FunctionCallInfoBaseData;
```