# Does PostgreSQL provide anything to dump fcinfo?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions, c

I'm looking to get into writing extension in C. I want to better understand what this argument is and how they get changed in different invocations. Is there anything that can dump this argument out or a method to debug the `fcinfo` argument?

In [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/302049/2639), I learned that it's actually a pointer to a `FunctionCallInfoBaseData` struct, but is there an easy way to dump that on function invocation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I created a module to dump `fcinfo` and `rsinfo` called `pg-dump-fcinfo`](https://github.com/EvanCarroll/pg-dump-fcinfo)

It provides `dump_fcinfo` which you can run this in different contexts,

```
=# \x
Expanded display is on.

=# SELECT * FROM dump_fcinfo();
-[ RECORD 1 ]--------------+--
sfrm_valuepercall          | t
sfrm_materialize           | t
sfrm_materialize_random    | f
sfrm_materialize_preferred | t
fmgrinfo_fn_nargs          | 0
tupledescdata_natts        | 7
tupledescdata_strict       | t
```